# What is an appropriate repeated-measures approach for statistically comparing results from two different methods?

Tags: r, paired-data, neuroimaging

I have a diffusion MRI dataset, with values of white matter tract volume and fractional anisotropy that were derived using tract masks generated from two different tractography software packages. I also have measures of subject age, image acquisition protocol (i.e. b-value used; 2-level, between-subjects factor), and a Diagnostic category (Diagnosed or Control subject; 2-level, between-subjects factor).

So far, I have used paired t-tests to compare volume and fractional anisotropy (FA) results derived from either software package. However, I would also like to statistically compare whether main effects for age (mean-centered), Diagnosis, and their interaction differ between the two software packages (while also controlling for a few covariates that measure subject motion as well as the effect of acquisition protocol).

What statistical method would be most appropriate to do so? So far, I have been leaning to either a repeated-measures ANCOVA or a linear mixed effects model, however neither seems appropriate given my within-subjects factor (Software-Package) only has two levels.

Comment: Please let me know if I should include an example of my dataset for clarification purposes.